# Python Random Array Sorting

Tags: python, arrays

[image]
I couldn't understand the algorythm that starts with for x in range(0,n): i couldn't understand whay did we use this statement

Comment: https://www.pythoncentral.io/pythons-range-function-explained/ has some nifty examples!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please don't post images of text that could be formatted and included in your post.

Comment: Thanks for your warning my friend

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in range(0, n): # Do what's in this loop n times (since x isn't used anywhere)

    # Make a list (size n) of random ints between min and max
    random_list = list(np.random.randint(min_value, max_value, size=n)

    # Sort this list
    random_list = array_sort(random_list)

    # Append it to your other list (called array)
    array.append(random_list)
```

Comment: #Sort this list , i thought that we  equalize  random_list  to the function that we created in the starting of code is it true ? Can you be more spesific by sort this list mean ?